# lack of acceleration mazda 3 sport

Tags: power

I have a mazda 3 sport diesel on a 07 plate it has 133000 on clock, I bought this car a couple of months ago and have noticed a lack of power in the lower gears. it struggles to overtake unless I have some momentum going but when I do get some speed up it seems ok. I have had it in a garage who have tried to do a forced re-gen but could not overide the code on the diagnostics machine, there is no dpf light showing and I am now thinking do I get rid. I do a 90 mile roundtrip to work regularly and find it very frustrating when sitting behind a slower vehicled and cant overtake unless I have a very clear road ahead, any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The DPF is a very likely problem if you lose large amounts of power, though if you do 90 miles daily then DPF should have no problems regenerating without intervention. There are other problems that could cause a significant lack of power on diesels (if there is no check engine light on):

- A really dirty air filter that needs replacing;
- A clogged fuel filter (already mentioned);
- A blocked EGR valve that needs cleaning;
- A turbocharger fault, like a stuck wastegate, faulty boost sensor or mechanical failure;
- Clogged exhaust causing backpressure, most likely at the catalytic converter;
- A faulty/dirty MAP/MAF which fails to calculate required fuel, should be accompanied by poor idle and/or clouds of black smoke out of the exhaust;
- A faulty temperature sensor that forces the engine to run in "cold" conditions, the gauge should give this away if it does not read a separate sensor;
- A stuck thermostat that does not allow reaching operating temperature, also should be given away by low temperature;
- Clogged injectors, usually accompanied by problems such as poor idle and difficult starting;
- A faulty fuel pump, usually accompanied by difficult starting and stalling;

Any other symptoms, like black smoke, poor idle, stuck temperature gauge, stalling?

Comment: Please forgive an ignorant question, what does DPF mean? I assume the F = failure or fault, but the rest I have no idea.

Comment: When I type DPF into a famous search engine the first thing that comes up is [a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diesel_particulate_filter) on a Diesel Particulate Filter

Comment: I agree, that's a great way to go. I have a feeling if I didn't know, others might not either, and putting the answer here, makes the repository of knowledge about this more complete.

Comment: @cdunn yes, the DPF is a diesel particulate filter, an often problematic part of the diesel emissions control. If the car is occasionally driven for a longer distance then the filter is regenerated automatically by temporarily increasing the exhaust temperature and burning off the particles as a result. Though many people do short distance city driving only, and some choose to completely remove it from their cars after it starts causing problems, as it is usually cheaper than fitting a new one.

Answer (score 2):

The fuel filter could be dirty, which would be restricting the fuel flow required for acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a split in one of your air hoses from the turbo.  This would let out the pressurized air produced by the turbo during boost.

Comment: Well, you could just edit your old answer.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing We are allowed to have more than one answer. What is the problem?

Comment: It's not about what's allowed. Separate answers for each possible cause sounds great, but it could get cluttery really fast if more people did that.

Comment: Or we should simply start all doing that and never combine different possible diagnoses, I would like that as well. In that case it will be easy to upvote what everyone thinks is the most likely answer. But now it's worse than either situation, when single answers and combined answers are thrown on the same question.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing  That is the problem with a long list of possible faults.  There are things in your answer I agree with and things I don't.  Do I up vote your answer or not?

Comment: That's what comments are for - we argue about it and the answer is modified to be the best it can be.